# Why is this core package being called?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to authenticate with Google through OAuth, and this is my server code

```
my.fetchTokens = function(code) {

    var endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    var params   = {
      code: code,
      client_id: Meteor.settings.google.CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: Meteor.settings.google.CLIENT_SECRET,
      redirect_uri: Meteor.settings.google.REDIRECT_URL,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    };

    try {
      response = HTTP.post(endpoint, { params: params });
    } catch (err) {
      throw _.extend(new Error("Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Google. " + err.message),
                     {response: err.response});
    }

    if (response.data.error) { // if the http response was a json object with an error attribute
      throw new Error("Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Google. " + response.data);
    }

    var tokens = {
      accessToken: response.data.access_token,
      refreshToken: response.data.refresh_token,
      expiresIn: response.data.expires_in,
      idToken: response.data.id_token
    };
    console.log(tokens);
    return tokens;
  };
```

But when I invoke this method, I get the following warnings

```
 W20150316-10:30:05.853(1) (oauth_server.js:71) Unable to base64 decode state from OAuth query: undefined
W20150316-10:30:05.854(1) (oauth_server.js:71) Unable to base64 decode state from OAuth query: undefined
W20150316-10:30:05.855(1) (oauth_server.js:71) Unable to base64 decode state from OAuth query: undefined
W20150316-10:30:05.855(1) (oauth_server.js:398) Error in OAuth Server: Match error: Expected string, got undefined
```

But I dont get why `oauth_server.js:71` is being referenced

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're calling `OAuth.openSecret` or `OAuth._redirectUri('google', config)`.

I assume one of these calls parses the current URL.

Comment: Nope, I changed them at it still happens